# mem___: bytes or chars

Tags: c

Do the mem___ functions e.g. memset take length in bytes or chars? Everything I've seen up to now has indicated bytes, but the CRT of this TI DSP with 16-bit chars I've been working with lately takes sizes in chars. Is this one of the deep, dark corners of the C language (like the fact that sizeof actually returns size in chars), or is TI's implementation nonstandard?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/ the documentation there says "Number of bytes to be set to the value."

Comment: `char`s __are__ bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C language is designed to support wildly exotic systems, so you should be able to keep most of the code in pure standard C. But you are going to need a lot of awareness for how the compiler translates the C to machine code. To the point where it is probably easier and faster to write the code in pure assembler...

Comment: To avoid ambiguity the term _octet_ is more useful that _byte_ if you are referring to specifically 8 bit words.  TI DSPs with 16 bit char are not physically capable of octet addressing.  You will find that stdint.h for example does not have `uint8_t` or `int8_t`.

Comment: Actuall TI makes DSPs that is byte addressable, e.g. c62xx/64xx/66xx. 16 bit word addressable machines are only C28xx and C55xx series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One `char` is guaranteed to be one byte by the C standard, so `memset` etc takes chars/bytes. There is however no guarantee over how many *bits* a `char`/byte has. This is defined by `CHAR_BIT` in limits.h.

If you insist on writing C for these obscure DSP:s, you have to read the compiler documentation in detail. See how they define a `char`, among other things. If I remember correctly, a `char` is usually implemented as 16 bits wide for the TI DSP:s.